# Im having trouble creating a zoom ability for my vtt

Tags: python-3.x, vtt

The main problem right now is that the player sprites disappear as soon as I zoom in or out the qrid scales correctly though. I had it working with the player sprites on screen then their movement stopped working. Got a little frustrated, then deleted the zoom altogether. Restarted, and now I'm here so I figured posting my first question because the internet didn't have the answers readily available.

```
import pygame as pg

class game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT = 1000, 700
        self.win = pg.display.set_mode((self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT), pg.RESIZABLE)
        self.mapsurface = pg.surface.Surface((10000, 10000))
        self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player("map assets/tokens/firegenasiwizard.png", self, 5, 5, self.mapsurface)
        self.jplayer = Player("map assets/tokens/goliathbarbarian.png", self, 4, 4, self.mapsurface)
        self.players = [self.player, self.jplayer]

    def event_tracker(self):
        global cellsize, spritesize
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type is pg.QUIT:
                pg.display.quit()
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
                for play in self.players:
                    if play.rect.x <= pos[0] <= play.rect.x + spritesize and \
                         play.rect.y <= pos[1] <= play.rect.y + spritesize and play.selected is False:
                     play.selected = True
                    elif play.rect.x <= pos[0] <= play.rect.x + spritesize and \
                         play.rect.y <= pos[1] <= play.rect.y + spritesize and play.selected is True:
                     play.selected = False
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                for play in self.players:
                    if event.key == pg.K_UP and play.selected is True:
                        play.move(dx=0, dy=-1)
                    if event.key == pg.K_DOWN and play.selected is True:
                        play.move(dx=0, dy=1)
                    if event.key == pg.K_LEFT and play.selected is True:
                        play.move(dx=-1, dy=0)
                    if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT and play.selected is True:
                        play.move(dx=1, dy=0)
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEWHEEL:
                if event.y > 0:
                    self.mapsurface = pg.transform.scale(self.mapsurface, (self.mapsurface.get_width() + 10,
                                                                           self.mapsurface.get_height() + 10))
                    cellsize += 10
                    spritesize += 10
                    for play in self.players:
                        play.scale(10)
                if event.y < 0:
                    self.mapsurface = pg.transform.scale(self.mapsurface, (self.mapsurface.get_width() - 10,
                                                                           self.mapsurface.get_height() - 10))
                    cellsize -= 10
                    spritesize -= 10
                    for play in self.players:
                        play.scale(-10)

    def draw_grid(self):
        self.mapsurface.fill(white)
        for x in range(0, self.mapsurface.get_width(), cellsize):
            pg.draw.line(self.mapsurface, black, (x, 0), (x, 10000), 1)
        for y in range(0, self.mapsurface.get_height(), cellsize):
            pg.draw.line(self.mapsurface, black, (0, y), (10000, y), 1)

    def draw_window(self):
        self.draw_grid()
        for play in self.players:
            play.draw()
        self.win.blit(self.mapsurface, (0, 0))
        pg.display.update()
```

Comment: What is "my vtt"? The tag has no description and the other questions appear to be about something else (or at least not Python).

Comment: i guess its a video file type but its also an abbreviation for a virtual table top, in ttrpgs like dungeons and dragons war hammer.